# How to retrieve all data from database using select option in php?

Tags: php, mysql, select, mysqli

So I have this `table` from my `database` that I want to `echo out` using `select` `option`. But I'm having trouble because I have an `option` where the user can add more options and I don't know how to set the value of it. Can you help me about it guys? thanks!

Here is my current code:

```
    <?php 

      while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) { 

    ?>

<select class="form-control input-sm">
      <option value="ABLE SEAMAN" <?php if($boiler_size == 'ABLE SEAMAN') { echo "selected"; } ?>>ABLE SEAMAN</option>
      <option value="AKO ITO" <?php if($boiler_size == 'AKO ITO') { echo "selected"; } ?>>AKO ITO</option>
      <option value="APPRENTICE" <?php if($boiler_size == 'APPRENTICE') { echo "selected"; } ?>>APPRENTICE</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I have provided you with a simple code to retrieve the output you can use this code and share thought about the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the count of the rows that has been selected from the DB since if the count is Zero it will be throwing error in the `while loop` or `foreach` as preferred usage for the showing up the dynamic select options.

Hence for showing up of the dynamic select options we need to do the following process.

```
<?php
$query="SELECT * FROM `TABLENAME` ORDER BY `id` DESC";
$stmt = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$count = $stmt->num_rows;
?>
<select class="form-control input-sm">
<?php
if($count==0)
{
    echo '<option value="">No Datas have been created Yet</option>';
}
else
{
    while($fetch = $stmt->fetch_assoc())
    {
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $fetch['id']; ?>"><?php echo $fetch['name']; ?></option>
    <?php   
    }
}
?>
</select>
```

Bu using the above codes you can fetch n-numbers of the option values from the DB and you can display it very easy without any confusions. The option value will be repeating till the loop ends and after that alone the `select` will end . So if the DB has `n-number` the while loop will repeat for n-number of times and will end up after that.

Comment: The guy one who has down-voted can mention up what is the reason for -1 for my answer so that it will be better for future corrections. I have used the `mysqli.*` statements alone and this loop will work fine.

Comment: The reason is simple - the very statement you made in your answer is not true. there is not a single problem with the while statement and a query returning no rows.

Comment: I have to change the function to get the row_count instead of the one i have used or i have to provide with the clear explanation regarding that @YourCommonSense..

Comment: @YourCommonSense. I have updated the code and my query to fetch the datas from the DB. Please share thoughts.

Comment: Please keep in mind that Stack Overflow is neither a forum nor a free tutoring portal. If you got a question you got to ask it the regular way.

Comment: Yup sure will follow it up from now on.. Here after will never ever do this mistake. Thanks for rectifying me.. :) @YourCommonSense.

Comment: @YourCommonSense. Can you pls reveoke up the negative point that you have provided me for this answer ..

Answer (score -1):

Simply write function :

```
 function populate_options($table_name, array $fields,  $selected_option = "") {
            $options = "<option></option>";
 $st = $pdo->prepare("SELECT distinct `$fields[0]`, `$fields[1]` FROM $table_name WHERE 1  GROUP BY `$fields[1]` ");
        $st->execute();
        $rowes = $st->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                if ($selected_option=="") {
        foreach ($rowes as $row) {
                        $options.= "<option value = '{$row->$fields[0]}'";
                        $options.= ">" . ucwords( $row->$fields[1] ) . "</option>";
                    }
                } else {
                    foreach ($rowes as $row) {
                        $options.= "<option value = '{$row->$fields[0]}'";
                        $options.= ((($selected_option == $row->$fields[0])) ? ' selected="selected"' : '') . ">" . ucwords($row->$fields[1] ). "</option>";
                    }
                }
            }

            return $options;
        }
```

and call in your code

```
<select class="form-control input-sm">
       <?php echo $populate_options("tbl_name", array('id', 'name'),$boiler_size); ?> 
</select>
```